# Function Arguments and Continuations

Tags: scheme, language-lawyer

My question is about function arguments in conjunction with continuations.
Specifically, what behavior is required, and what is allowed.

Suppose you have a function call `(f arg1 arg2 arg3)`.  I realize that
a compliant Scheme implementation is allowed to evaluate the arguments
`arg1`, `arg2`, and `arg3` in any order.  That's fine.  But now suppose
that, say, `arg2` creates a continuation.  In general, some of the other
arguments may be evaluated before `arg2` is evaluated, and some may be
evaluated after `arg2` is evaluated.

Suppose that, in the Scheme implementation we're using, `arg1` is
evaluated before `arg2`.  Further, suppose that `f` modifies its local
copy of the first argument.  Later, when the continuation created
during the evaluation of `arg2` is called, `arg3` will be evaluated
again and `f` will be called.

The question is this: When `f` is called a second time, via the
continuation, what value must/may its first argument have?  Does it
need to be the same value that `arg1` evaluated to?  Or may it be the
modified value from the previous call to `f`?  (Again, this example
assumes that `arg1` is evaluated before `arg2`, but the same issue
applies with different argument evaluation orders.  I.e., if `arg3` is
evaluated before `arg2`, then the question applies to `arg3`.)

I have tried this in a couple of Scheme implementations, and have obtained
differing results.  I took into account different orders of evaluation of
the arguments (it's easy to track it by having the argument expressions
log when they're being evaluated).  Ignoring that difference, one
implementation always used the original argument values, and another
sometimes used the original argument values, and sometimes used the
modified argument values, depending on whether `f` was an inline
lambda vs. a global function.  Presumably the difference is due to
whether the actual arguments end up being copied into the function's
local variables, or whether they are used in-place.

Here is a version that uses a global function:

```
(define (bar x cc y)
    (set! x (* x 2))
    (set! y (* y 3))
    (format #t "~a ~a\n" x y)
    cc)

(define (foo a b)
    (let* ((first #t)
           (cb (bar
                (+ a 10)
                (call/cc (lambda (x) x))
                (+ b 100))))
        (if first
            (begin
                (set! first #f)
                cb)
            (cb '()))))

(define cc (foo 1 2))
(call/cc cc)
(call/cc cc)
```

The above version uses the original argument values when calling
the function `bar` in both of the Scheme implementations that I tested.
The function `bar` sees `11` for the first argument and `102` for the
third argument each time it is called.  The output is:

```
22 306
22 306
22 306
```

Now, here is a version that replaces the global function with an inline
lambda:

```
(define (foo a b)
    (let* ((first #t)
           (cb ((lambda (x cc y)
                    (set! x (* x 2))
                    (set! y (* y 3))
                    (format #t "~a ~a\n" x y)
                    cc)
                (+ a 10)
                (call/cc (lambda (x) x))
                (+ b 100))))
        (if first
            (begin
                (set! first #f)
                cb)
            (cb '()))))

(define cc (foo 1 2))
(call/cc cc)
(call/cc cc)
```

In one of the Scheme implementations I tested (BiwaScheme), this
behaves the same as the previous version.  I.e., the called function
always sees the original argument values.

In another Scheme implementation (Gosh/Gauche), this behaves
differently from the previous version.  In this case, the called
function uses the modified value of the first argument.  In other
words, it handles the inline lambda differently, taking advantage of
the fact that it can see the function definition, and is presumably
using a more direct argument passing mechanism that avoids having to
copy them.  Since it isn't copying the arguments, the ones that were
evaluated before the continuation point retain their modified values.
The lambda sees `11` and `102` for the first and third arguments the
first time, then it sees `22` and `102` the second time, and `44` and
`102` the third time.  So the continuation is picking up the modified
argument values.  The output is:

```
22 306
44 306
88 306
```

So again, my question is this:  Are both behaviors allowed by the
Scheme standard (R6RS and/or R7RS)?  Or does Scheme in fact require
that the original argument values be used when the continuation is
invoked?

Update: I originally reported that the Gauche Scheme implementation
gave the three different sets of values shown above.  That was true,
but only for certain versions of Gauche.  The version I originally
tested was Gauche 0.9.3.3, which shows the three different sets of
values.  I later found a site that has three different versions of
Gauche.  The oldest, Gauche 0.9.4, also shows the three different
sets of values.  But the two newer versions, Gauche 0.9.5 and Gauche
0.9.8, both show the repeated values:

```
22 306
22 306
22 306
```

This argues pretty strongly that this was considered a bug which
has since been fixed (just as everyone has been saying).

Comment: This sounds like a bug in the second implementation. It has nothing to do with continuations. Assigning a local variable should have no effect outside of the function.

Comment: @Barmar This difference can only be exposed by continuations.  Just calling the function isn't the problem.  The problem is when a continuation is invoked, returning control to a point *after* an actual argument has been evaluated but *before* the function has been called.  If the called function modifies its arguments, then the original arguments would need to be copied to buffer them from the effects of the previous call to the function.

Comment: OK, it's still a bug. Setting `x` inside the function has no effect on the value outside the function.

Comment: @Barmar You could be right, but it really depends on how continuations are defined.  The unusual thing about my examples is that the continuation is created while the arguments to the function are still being evaluated.  You wouldn't normally do this, but if you do, it's not clear whether it needs to preserve the original argument values or whether you're invoking undefined behavior in that case.  It's clearly the result of an optimization.  It's just not clear whether that optimization is valid.

Comment: It really shouldn't matter. We're talking about variable scopes, they're local to each function.

Comment: @Barmar That's a good point.  In this case, the called function is making changes that affect the caller's environment, in the sense that a subsequent call, through a continuation, is affected by it.  I just didn't know if there was a provision for this in the language spec.  It's clearly due to an optimization that isn't performed unless the function definition is visible (e.g. the inline lambda).

Comment: Oh, we're talking about the `first` variable. OK, since the order of evaluation of function arguments isn't specified, anything that has side effects that depends on a particular order isn't well defined.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, but the question is, is there *some* argument evaluation order for which this behavior is allowed?  In the case of Gauche, arguments are evaluated left-to-right in this example.  If they were evaluated right-to-left, then the third argument would exhibit the problem.  As long as *some* argument is evaluated before the second argument, this will expose the problem (if it exists).

Comment: As you said, the order of argument evaluation isn't specified. So if your program gets different results depending on the order, it's a bug in your application.

Comment: You don't need continuations to demonstrate that. A simple `(list (write 1) (write 2))` will show the problem. It can write either `1 2` or `2 1`

Comment: @Barmar No, this is *not* an issue with evaluation order, and your list example has nothing to do with it.  The question is this:  After evaluating an argument, and passing it to a function, if a continuation is invoked that returns control to the evaluation of the argument list, is it required to use the original value of that argument in the subsequent call, or is it allowed to use the modified value?  While evaluation order affects the symptom, it is not the cause of the problem.  The problem can only be exhibited with continuations.

Comment: @Barmar Here's what's needed to demonstrate this problem:  At least *some* argument must be evaluated *before* the argument that creates the continuation is evaluated.  As long as that's the case, then this example detects whether that argument is copied, or whether it is stored in-place in the argument list.  In this example, if the evaluation order were reversed, the problem would be seen with the third argument rather than the first.  It's beside the point.

Comment: @Barmar Perhaps it would help if I explained it this way:  When continuations are possible, is Scheme required to copy arguments that are evaluated before the continuation is created?  Again, this is only an issue for continuations.  Evaluation order affects the symptom, but not the problem.

Comment: Nothing is ever copied in Scheme, unless you do it explicitly in your code. Everything is just references to objects. Arguments are evaluated, they return object references. Continuations simply capture the state of the ongoing computation.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, I didn't describe it correctly.  What I meant is, are the *references* to the arguments required to be copied.  If they are, then when the called function changes its arguments, those copied references get replaced, but the original references are still saved, and used when the continuation is invoked.  If they are not, then when the called function changed its arguments, the subsequent call from the continuation passes those *replaced* references.  The code I posted demonstrates this very clearly.

Comment: @Barmar I could explain this in more detail if it would help, but perhaps a private conversation would make sense.  I know exactly what's going on.  My question isn't about debugging a problem I don't understand.  It's about what the language requires.  Is the behavior that demonstrates the modified argument value allowed, or is it disallowed?

Comment: I think you need to discuss it with someone who knows more about continuation passing than me.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I posted here.  I know what it's doing, but I don't know much about what is required by a compliant Scheme implementation.  The optimization is appealing, but it opens the door for behavior like this.  If the original values must be preserved, then it forces references to be copied that could otherwise be used directly.  The first example doesn't permit that optimization, so the argument references are presumably copied into a list, which avoids this.

Comment: @Barmar Keep in mind that this isn't a problem in some code that I wrote.  It was a carefully constructed exampled specifically intended to test for whether this copying is being performed.  At first, I wasn't able to expose a case where it wasn't, but once I replaced the function call with an inline lambda call, it changed.  The same problem occurs if the lambda call is replaced with a `let`.

Comment: I'm not saying this is the wrong place to post the question. Just that you've gotten beyond my area of expertise, so I'm not the right person to chat with.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for your help.  Hopefully some Scheme expert will be able to answer it. I'm just not familiar enough with the requirements of R7RS to know if it addresses this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A continuation will literally create a copy of the stack in the moment of calling call/cc, copy that is also called a `control-point`.  The continuation also stores inside it a copy of the current dynamic environment (more precisely, of the state-space from the dynamic-wind module) and a copy of the thread-local state.

So, when you reactivate the continuation, everything will continue from the moment when it was saved.  If some arguments were previously evaluated, their evaluation is saved on the stack and the rest of arguments will be re-evaluated a second time.  (as a remark, the dynamic state in scheme is implemented over the dynamic-wind module, so saving the dynamic state involved saving the state of dynamic wind, which is a combination between stack and the state-space (a tree keeping the in-out thunks for dynamic-wind calls)).

The stack starts from the top-level (actually there are other stacklets that represent continuations of the shutdown procedures, but those are touched only when you finish your code), they are not memorized when you call call/cc.  So, if in a file/repl you gave 2 expressions, such as

```
(+ (f 1) 2)
(display "ok")
```

each of these expressions will have its own stacklet, so saving the continuation within `f` won't re-evaluate the `display`.

I think this should be enough to analyse your problem.  The arguments are evaluated in unspecified order.

EDIT:

Concerning the answer of `foo`, for sure it is not correct `22 306 44 306 88 306` but it's correct `22 306 22 306 22 306`.

I never used any of these 2 implementations.  It is a bug in the implementation that does not bind `x` after each [invocation of the (lambda (x cc y) ...)](http://www.r6rs.org/final/html/r6rs/r6rs-Z-H-4.html#node_sec_1.3), as the capture of the continuation is made outside the lambda().

The implementation bug seems obvious, it's in their generation of Scode -- they keep `x` on the stack, despite the fact that `set! x` was present, which should be an indicator to allocate `x` as a box on the heap.

Comment: Thanks.  I need to look at this more closely, but it sounds like you're saying the Gauche implementation isn't handling this correctly, and that it's a bug, because the lambda call should not be able to affect the previously evaluated arguments in the caller.  That makes sense.  I just wasn't sure if Scheme required it.

Comment: By the way, both of the Scheme implementations I tested have free web-based implementations, so I didn't actually need to install it.  Gosh/Gauche is at [this URL](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_scheme_online.php).  You can paste your code on the left, then click "execute" and it will run it on their server, displaying the results on the right.

Comment: @TomKarzes that's right I said.  They save the value of X on the stack and after that they capture the continuation.   If you move cc on the first position, it will be evaluated first and don't capture the X. X being bound locally, should not be influenced by previously bound X.  The binding it's itself an operation that here is not executed correctly, etc.

Comment: I updated my post to reflect the results from newer versions of Gauche, which fix this bug (see the bottom of the post).

Answer (score 1):

While the evaluation order is undefined in the report **it is not undefined in an implementtions CPS code**. Eg.

`(f (+ x 4) (call/cc cont-fun))`, where x is a free variable,  becomes either:

```
(call/cc& 
 cont-fun&
 (lambda (v2)
   (+& x 
       4
       (lambda (v1)
         (f& v1 v2 halt&))))
```

Or:

```
(+& x 
    4
    (lambda (v1)
      (call/cc& 
       cont-fun&
       (lambda (v2)
         (f& v1 v2 halt&)))))
```

So if the continuation function `cont-fun&` mutates `x` this will have an impact of the result in the version that evaluates the arguments right to left since the addition is done in the continuation of it, but in the second version mutating `x` will not affect the addition since the value is already computed in the passed value `v2` and in the event the continuation is captured and rerun this value will never be recomputed. In the first version though you always compute `v1` so here mutating the free variable `x` will affect the result.

If you as a developer wants to avoid this you `let*` the damn thing:

```
(let* ((a2 (call/cc cont-fun))
       (a1 (+ x 4)))
  (f a1 a2))
```

This code will force the behavior of the addition always being in the continuation of determining `a2`.

Now I avoided using your mutating examples, but in reality those are just bindings being rerouted. You have overcomplicated `bar` as the `set!` does not have any lasting effect. It is always the same as:

```
(define (bar x cc y)
  (format #t "~a ~a\n" (* x 2) (* y 3))
  cc)
```

The continuation caught in:

```
(bar (+ a 10)
     (call/cc (lambda (x) x))
     (+ b 100))
```

Regardless of the order we know the call to `bar` is the final continuation after evaluating all 3 expressions and then do the body of the `let*` the first and the 2 consecutive times.

Your second version doesn't change anything since the function doesn't rely on free variables. How the consecutive call to the continuation gave you 44 and 88 is most definitely a compiler optimization that fails. It shouldn't do that. I would have reported it as a bug.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  But the instances of `set!` in the lambda body are necessary to produce the questionable results that I reported, i.e. `22 306`, then `44 306`, then `88 306`.  Without them, you just get `22 306` three times, which is clearly acceptable.  The problem isn't with reevaluating the arguments that are evaluated after the `call/cc`.  The problem is with the results of the arguments that are evaluated *before* the `call/cc`.  If my example, the first `set!` was changing the *caller's* copy of  the first argument, and that modified value was used in the continuation call.

Comment: So the question is whether the result of any of the `set!` invocations should affect the caller's state, so that when the continuation is invoked, the *modified* value is used as the argument to the lambda, rather than the original value.  That's why the `set!` instances are key to producing the questionable behavior.  My question was not how the behavior arises, but whether it is allowed by the Scheme standard.

Comment: @TomKarzes It is, as I wrote in the end of my asnwer, a bug. The second version either is exactly the same as the first where the evaluation of the lambda happens once, but it can also create a new procedure object each time that does the same that gets garbage collected. Iits in the second one something crazy is happening where an optimization perhaps creates a feature not part of the scheme standard.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  Clearly the inline lambda version is performing an optimization that the named function call isn't.  I assume it's avoiding copying the evaluated arguments, but as a result is vulnerable to the problem.

Comment: I updated my post to reflect the results from newer versions of Gauche, which fix this bug (see the bottom of the post).