# Why this continuation application leads to infinite loop

Tags: racket, continuations

I'm trying to execute the following simple function inside racket repl:

```
(define (f x)
  (let ((cont null))
    (println (+ 10 (call/cc (lambda (cc)                              
                              (set! cont cc)
                              10))))
    cont))

((f 1) 10)
```

this call inifinitely prints `20`, while i'm expecting it to be printed at most twice (once for `(f 1)`, and once for continuation procedure call)

How can you interpret this behavior?

**update**

however when assigned to some top-level var it works:

```
> (define kont (f 1))
;;=> 20
> (kont 12)
;;=> 22
```

Can't see what's the conceptual difference

Comment: hmm. btw I tried it with `((f 1) 30)`, and it printed 20 once and then went berserk printing `40` over and over.

Comment: yeah, this is exactly what i see. Cannot explain it

Comment: I'd expect something like `#<continuation>` be returned to REPL after the second printing.

Comment: The difference of "(define kont (f 1))" and invoking it right away is detailed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68778639/what-determines-the-outer-boundary-of-a-scheme-continuation/68786546#68786546